# Unable to delete file in script

Tags: file, powershell, file-io, delete-file

Going out of my mind over here. 
I have a script where I'm parsing a folder full of tifs, and breaking the files up into sub-folders to limit the number of pages to around 60 per folder. If a document is very large it gets its own folder.

The problem is that the process is locking up the files, so they cannot be deleted. Not every file though, most of them work fine, and my end clean-up portion of the script gets rid of everything else.

I wrote a lot of work-around sections to my code to fix this issue, and now it is pretty bad looking

```
    #Large Documents
Get-ChildItem -Path "$directory" -recurse -filter "*.tif" | foreach {
    $file = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::FromFile($_.Fullname);
    $pagecount = $file.GetFrameCount($file.FrameDimensionsList[0]); 
    if ($pagecount -gt $MaxSize){
        $total = $total + $pagecount;
        $name = $_.Basename;
        New-Item $name -ItemType directory;
        Copy-Item $_.fullname -Destination $name;
        #Copy-Item $name".DS" -Destination $processingDir;
        Write-Host "Sleeping in large doc loop";
        $file.Dispose;
        Write-Host "Dispose file object";
        Write-Host $_.Fullname
        $storename = $_.Fullname
        $largeFiles = $largeFiles + $storename      
        Write-Host "Storing to array: " $largeFiles[$index];
        $index = $index + 1;
        sleep(15);
    }
}
while ($delInd -lt $largeFiles.Count){
    Write-Host "Deleting: " $largeFiles[$delInd];
    Remove-Item $largeFiles[$delInd] -Force;
    $delInd = $delInd + 1;
}
```

I'm absolutely perplexed by this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Locking may be done by file indexer or by antivirus.  Try SysInternals tools (for example, Handles.exe -- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) to see what processes are using the files.

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? If so, post it up on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand with `$file.Dispose` you do not force underlying object to close the file. `Dispose` is a method and, in PowerShell (like in C#), to invoke a method you have to use `()`. So try `$file.Dispose()`.

piece of advice : you can avoid `;` at the end of the lines